# Rota de grupo não funciona no Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Boa noite galera, tudo bem? Estou com um problema nas rotas do Laravel 5. Tenho um grupo de rotas para o painel administrativo do site (rotas com prefixo painel) e dentro do grupo eu quero que a primeira página fique exatamente na "raiz". Veja o código abaixo:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel', 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function(){

    // Login Routes
    Route::get('/', 'LoginController@getLogin');
]);
```

Desse jeito quando acesso 'localhost/painel' não abre, aparece 404. Já se eu coloco assim:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'painel', 'namespace' => 'Backend'], function(){

    // Login Routes
    Route::get('/teste', 'LoginController@getLogin');
]);
```

e acesso 'localhost/painel/teste' funciona. Quero que essa rota funcione quando acessar apenas 'localhost/painel'. Alguém sabe o que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado!

Comment: você poderia me mostrar o que acontece quando você lista as rotas: php artisan route:list

Comment: Mas você tem dois grupos? não entendi

Answer (score -1):

Já tentou criar a rota '/painel' fora do grupo?

Acredito que assim funcionará :)

```
 Route::get('/painel', 'LoginController@getLogin');
```

Ela deve ficar antes do grupo no arquivo de rotas.

Answer (score -1):

Faltou a rota default dentro do group, mantenha as duas.

```
// Rota Default
Route::get('/', 'LoginController@getLogin');

// Login Routes
Route::get('/teste', 'LoginController@getLogin');
```